# Agrupar notificaciones segun el remitente

Tags: android, push-notification, group-by, notificaciones

Tengo una app que implementa Cloud Functions y cuando un usuario manda un mensaje se activa una función que le manda al usuario que recibe el mensaje una notificación. Mi problema consiste en que al mandar varios mensajes consecutivos sobrescribe la notificación en si:

> Titulo de notificacion 1: Ada
>
> Texto de la notificacion 1: Hola como estas
>
> Texto de notificacion 2: Ada
>
> Texto de la notificacion 2: Me recibes?

Para hacerme explicar mejor... En caso de que esos dos mensajes (aunque sean más el resultado es el mismo) sean mandados muestra la 1 notificación, y al activarse la función en el 2 mensaje lo que hace es que la notificación que tenia con el texto de notificación 1 se sobrescriba con el de la segunda.

Como puedo lograr que cuando una persona te escriba varios mensajes consecutivos se agrupen en una conversación estilo Whatsapp o Telegram??

Lo que he intentado:

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getNotification());
                createMessageNotificationChanel();

                String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
                Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + body);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID))
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_chat)
                        .setGroup(getString(R.string.MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID))
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
                        .setSubText("Nuevo mensaje")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                                .addLine(body))
                        .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL(remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon()))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .setContentIntent(intent);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notificationManager.notify(R.integer.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_CHANEL_ID, builder.build());
            }

 private void createMessageNotificationChanel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.message_chanel);
        String description = getString(R.string.message_channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.MESSAGE_CHANNEL_ID), name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Que necesito agregar o cambiar para lograr ese tipo de comportamiento??

Comment: Hola  @AlexRivas ya revisaste la respuesta, para la completa implementación te sugiero usar Firebase Realtime Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las notificaciones se sobreescriben ya que tienes un problema debido a que estas definiendo el mismo id para la notificación, en realidad no se debe definir en este punto el id del canal pero si el de la notificacion, **si defines el mismo id al generar la notificación estas se estaran sobreescribiendo ya que debes recordar este valor debe ser unico para cada notificación**:

```
  // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notificationManager.notify(R.integer.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_CHANEL_ID, builder.build());
```

Para solucionar esto crea una variable de clase:

```
int idNotification;
```

la cual usaras como id de la notificación y se estará incrementando cada vez que crees una notificación.

```
notificationManager.notify(idNotification++, builder.build());
```

De esta forma se mostraran los mensajes consecutivamente como lo deseas.

```
Titulo de notificacion 1: Ada

Texto de la notificacion 1: Hola como estas

Texto de notificacion 2: Ada

Texto de la notificacion 2: Me recibes?
```

---

**El ordenar las notificaciones cronologicamente hasta el dìa de hoy no es posible mediante còdigo**, en este caso el usuario tendrìa que configurar su dispositivo para realizar dicha acciòn.

Aquì una discusiòn sobre este tema:

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/2638311?hl=en

--

**Si deseas obtener y enviar los mensajes en tiempo real, además que estos se ordenen cronológicamente, la opciòn es usar Firebase Realtime Database**,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es un lab que seguramente te ayudarà:

[Construir un chat amigable](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#6)

Comment: Jorge ahora me salen todas pero no se agrupan segun el remitente, como puedo lograr eso??

Comment: Lo que quiero lograr es lo que hacen aplicaciones como Whatsapp o Telegram... Otra cosa como puedo lograr que las notificaciones no se envien si estoy dentro del chat con la persona de la que obtengo la notificacion?

Comment: Alex, desgraciadamente lo que comentas no es posible ya que el servidor puede tardar en ocasiones algunos segundos  en enviar el mensaje y podrìa no estar ordenados cronologicamente, si deseas realizar un chat con mensajes en tiempo real definiitavmente la solucion es usar Firebas, agregue la informaciòn a mi respuesta,  @AlexRivas  saludos.

Comment: Jorgesys uso firestore para el chat junto con una fucion en cloud functions, las notificaciones se mandan bien pero las pone regadas, no me interesa el orden en si solo agruparlas bajo el mismo remitente por ejemplo Alex Rivas y todos sus mensajes, el orden en si no importa

Comment: En el caso de push notifications, el server Google es el que se encarga de enviar las notificaciones, el problema aquí es que el cliente puede recibir notificaciones a destiempo aun y cuando se enviaron antes que otras por esa razón, realizar este tipo de chat usando notificaciones no sería una solución real.

Comment: y no hay forma de sobreescribir la notificacion con los ultimos mensajes no leidos? esa seria una buena solucion no? como puedo leer las notifcaciones en la bandeja de entrada para añadirle una linea

Comment: si ya me di cuenta que la solucion es tener un mapa con los mensajes no leidos por el usuario y ese mapa es el que debo enviar como notificacion y asi lograr el resultado que quiero muchas gracias por la ayuda la marco como correcta. @Jorgesys me di cuenta gracias a ti salu2 amigo